# Disable Automated PDF Analysis in iOS 16 PDFKit

Tags: ocr, ios16, ios-pdfkit, visionkit, ipados16

Since the upgrade to iPadOS 16, Xcode's console has been filled with messages such as `[VKImageAnalyzer processRequest:] returned 0` or `[VKImageAnalyzer processRequest:] block returned NULL analysis` - this happens in the simulator, and on the physical device I get warnings about fonts, such as `CoreText performance note: Client called CTFontCreateWithName() using name "Times-Roman" and got font with PostScript name "TimesNewRomanPSMT". For best performance, only use PostScript names when calling this API.`

My app displays PDF files of music scores by using PDFKit, and therefore the automated image analysis of the PDF files, introduced in iOS 16, is completely irrelevant to it. In addition to spamming the console, this feature also consumes unnecessary resources.

I couldn't find anywhere documentation on a way to disable the automated PDF analysis in PDFKit. Any thoughts would be very welcome.

Comment: Did you find the solution? Have the same here

Comment: No. I think we have to report this on the developers' feedback tool, and ask for an API.